# How to synchronize Excel with Google Docs spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-docs, google-sync

This feature is not officially suported by Google. Do you know if is there a way or a product that allows to synchronize the changes performed in excel into a google spread sheet?

1. Create file in excel
2. Upload it to gDocs
3. Modify it in gDocs
4. Download it to excel
5. Modify it in excel
6. Synchonize it with gDocs.

All of the above steps are supported but 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running Office 2003 or Office 2007, use [OffiSync](http://offisync.com/). It's free.

Comment: mmhh Excel 2008 :P on Mac

Comment: Ouch. I didn't see that coming!

Comment: OffiSync has been acquired by [Jive Software](https://www.jivesoftware.com/) as of May 2011 and that product is no longer available to new customers.

Answer (score 1):

[Syncplicity](http://syncplicity.com/) works for me, although the sync sometimes takes a little while...

> Sync files with all your computers. Access them from all your mobile
>   devices. Share them without changing your work habits. Make sure
>   everything is backed up. All with the control and security you need.